# How to save text from textbox to file (Tkinter)

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Whenever the function `save()` runs I get an error saying that the variable that holds the `Text()` function does not exist. I want the GUI to save whatever is inputted at the point when the Activate button is pressed.

```
from tkinter.ttk import *

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent= None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("TL;DR")
        self.style = Style() 
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=7)
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(5, pad=7)

        lbl = Label(self, text="Enter Text")
        lbl.grid(sticky=W, pady=4, padx=5)



        area = Text(self)
        area.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, 
            padx=5, sticky=E+W+S+N)

        abtn = Button(self, text="Activate", command= self.save)
        abtn.grid(row=1, column=3)



        cbtn = Button(self, text="Close", command = self.client_exit)
        cbtn.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=4)

        hbtn = Button(self, text="Help", command= self.help1)
        hbtn.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5)


    def save(self):
        text = self.area.get("1.0",'end-1c')
        with open("filepy.txt", "a") as outf:
            outf.write(text)

    def help1(self):
        messagebox.showinfo('Help')


    def client_exit(self):              
        exit()

def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("400x300+300+300")
    app = Example(root)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My question is: **how do I save any text in the TextBox when the activate button is pressed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `save()` method, you are trying to access `self.area` but you did not created it.

```
area = Text(self) # class variable
self.area = Text(self)# instance variable
```

To be able to use `self` to access `area` you should change your code:

```
...

self.area = Text(self)
self.area.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, 
        padx=5, sticky=E+W+S+N)

...
```

Comment: @Marko Marsenic  Check this.